# Is it possible for a binary computable function to "execute" an unary computable function?

Tags: computability, recursion, turing-machines

let's have a computable binary function $\phi_e(x,y)$, from the canonical ordering. Is it possible to have such $e$, that $\phi_e(x,y)=\phi_x(y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the answer is **yes** is the statement of the Universal Turing Machine (UTM) theorem. The indices $e$ with this property are exactly the indices of UTMs.